# How to connect mongodb remote server using Batch script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB remote server using a batch script to update collections:

```
cd Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin
mongo.exe 
mongo.exe --eval "use mydb"
pause
```

I found solutions if the database is located within the local machine. I couldn't find any correct solution for remote servers.
Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Could you please describe what do you exactly expect? Just connection and opening the remote console or something else?

Comment: I want to connect to database and then i will update collection on specific conditions.I need help with connection!

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming you just want to connect to MongoDB server and open `mongoshell`.

You need `mongoshell` installed to connect to remote MongoDB. [Here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/) are more details.

You can use `--username` and `--password` options to connect using specific user credentials.

You can refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/) for how to use mongoshell.

Comment: hey, i installed mongoshell.But i coudn't connect to database from shell. mongodb://username@hostname/mydb.                                                                           I used the above syntax ,it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Nagavarsha, what do you mean doesn't work. Could you please be specific.

Comment: can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433102/setdate-not-setting-date-properly-inside-eval-in-batch-script this?