# setDate not setting date properly inside eval in batch script

Tags: mongodb, date, datetime, batch-file

--eval "var date = new Date(); date.setDate(date.getDate()-10)"'
pause

new Date() gives me the current date. I'm trying to get 10 days back date,but setDate() not setting the date correctly.I'm doing it through batch script.
I got this 1576031482772 after evaluating date.setDate(date.getDate()-10) .Please help me find a solution.

Comment: add the batch script to your question.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c 'mongo "mongodb://username:password@host/mydb?replicaSet=rs01&authSource=admin" --eval "var date = new Date(); date.setDate(date.getDate()-10)"'

Comment: Could you please give more details of your problem and what solutions you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. The signature of `setDate` is as follows. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

> Parameters

It accepts one parameter, it should be number as a day value.

> Return Value

It returns milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date

> Solution

You are actually setting the day value of date. So If you want to retrieve the value, just use `date.getDate()`. Which will be the new date.

For more details, how it works, you can refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).